# reorder moodle login page

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, moodle

Is it possible to change the order of the logins on a moodle login page? I want to have Oauth2 above the email login.
(Moodle 2.9 with email self registration and Oauth2 login with facebook and google+.)

I tried moving this part:
https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_29_STABLE/login/index_form.html#L112

above the login to here:
https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_29_STABLE/login/index_form.html#L26

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: loginform.mustache templates are responsible for the HTML view.  you can directly change code form /lib/templates/loginform.mustache. 

Another way is overriding the templates from your theme. Copy and pest loginform.mustache into your theme templates/ folder and edit as you require.

Answer (score 1):

```css
<style>
.social-button.google {
    left: 320px;
    top: 260px;
position: absolute;
}
.loginpanel {    
    margin-top: 104px !important;
}</style>
```

Add this CSS style in index_form.html and changes base on your requirnment.
This not permanent solution but it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself but I'm guessing you can change the order via site admin -> plugins -> authentication -> manage plugins.

Or direct to `/admin/settings.php?section=manageauths`

There are up/down buttons to change the order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried that before and it didn't change anything.